# How to stop Job in Spring Batch remote chunking, when slaves are completed?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using this example as a starting point for a spring batch app, using remote chunking: 
https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-remote-chunking-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/benas/MasterConfiguration.java
Over this example, I've added my custom readers/writers, but I didn't changed any configuration. The example works fine, except that I can not stop the job after all slaves are completed.

I've tried using a JobListner, to stop the job inside 'afterJob' method, but no results.

```
public class MyJobExecutionListener implements JobExecutionListener {

@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    System.out.println("afterJob start~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println(jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.getStartTime());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.getEndTime());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.isRunning());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.isStopping());

    jobExecution.stop();

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!");
    System.out.println(jobExecution.isRunning());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.isStopping());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.getEndTime());


    System.out.println("afterJob end~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
}
```

}

jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode() is COMPLETED
jobExecution.isStopping() is true, but the app is still running.

To run the app, I'm using SpringBoot (instead running it as unit test, as it is in the example)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AppStarter {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! start");
      SpringApplication.run(AppStarter.class, args);

   }
}
```

Is there a way to stop the app when completed ?

Comment: The master should be stopped automatically. There is something else preventing the application context from stopping (either a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` or some Spring Integration components that need to be explicitly stopped). Do you have one of those in your app? I know you said you didn't changed any configuration but since you are using Spring Boot, it might have added a couple of things implicitly. Can you share your repo?

Comment: The code is local, on a VM, so I can not publish it on a public repo. In the master configuration class, I have:

`
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableIntegration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
`

Comment: I am also using JMS to communicate between master and slaves:

`@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
  
  return IntegrationFlows.from(masterRequests())
    .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory).destination("requests"))
    .get();
 }

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow masterInboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
  return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory).destination("replies"))
    .channel(masterReplies())
    .get();
 }`

Comment: sorry for formatting, I'm still getting used with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the application context of the master explicitly with something like:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(YourMasterApp.class, args);
context.close();
```

This will ensure the master side has finished running the job and then close the application context.

A couple of notes though:

- You can find the same sample in the official samples repo here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#remote-chunking-sample. The personal repo you used as a starting point may be deleted at any time
- Using `jobExecution.stop()` in the `afterJob` method of the listener make no sense because this `afterJob` method is almost the [last statement](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/AbstractJob.java#L359) before ending the job anyway. Moreover, this `jobExecution.stop()` will be removed in a future version (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1987)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I've received some updates and I have to start the Job from a controller. 

Better for me, since it can be started using something like 
`jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());`

So, I'll have access to the JobLauncher and have easier control (at least for me).